# attaching javascript to page elements on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

The issue I am having is that I have a set of modals that are tied to a media query structure.
 I need to be able to attach all Javascript at once, to open the two modals at each page size.
 I converted from `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName`, and it is no longer recognizing any of the script calls I am making.

HTML:

```
<div id="visibleForRegularSizeAndMed" class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs no-padding backgroundImageForPage" style="height:650px">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="background-color:whitesmoke; height:250px;position:absolute;bottom:1px">
      <div class="col-md-4 centerDiv" style="border-right:1px solid black">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:70%">
          <h3><strong class="footerBoxHeader">Listen</strong></h3>
          <p>
            <span>5 minute audio/video overview of what to expect from the online Compliance Tutorial.</span>
            <audio controls style="margin-top:51px;" id="explorerStyle">
              <source src="~/Training/Compliance/ar/10165676.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 centerDiv" style="border-right:1px solid black">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:70%">
          <h3><strong class="footerBoxHeader">Train</strong></h3>
          <p>
            <img class="myImg ComplianceImages" src="~/Images/complianceTraining/set1.jpg" alt="First Compliance Slide" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 centerDiv">
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:89%">
          <h3><strong class="footerBoxHeader">Receive Certificate</strong></h3>
          <p>
            <img class="myImg2 ComplianceImages" src="" alt="Small" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 // add javascript to handle popup images  in Compliance Training Section "train"
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal')[0];
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg')[0];
img.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// add javascript to handle popup images  in Compliance Training Section "Receive Certificate"
var modal2 = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal2')[1];
var img2 = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg2')[1];
var modalImg2 = document.getElementsByClassName("img02")[1];
img2.onclick = function () {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
```

Modals:

```
<div class="modal myModal">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic">

    </div>
    </div>


<div class="modal myModal2">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <img class="modal-content img02" src="~/Images/complianceTraining/Certificate.jpg" alt="Completion Certificate for Compliance Training">
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

to clarify, the resizing is not actually changing the page, but hiding parts of the page on resize, thus the hidden-sm, hidden-xs, etc...

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/progSrCa/3ey03wh5/

Comment: so in fact your css is overriding your js set properties... so add a subclass that is just changed by js...

Comment: @Jonasw Could you be more specific with the location that you are seeing this issue please? I am not sure exactly what you are looking at where the issue is occurring.

Comment: because of to much unnecessary code i wasnt able to find your problem. thats why i guess the css is setting other rules to your modals than you want...

Comment: You start your JS with a reference to the class myModal, but there's no element with this class in your HTML. Could you provide us with a JSFiddle? This could help to understand the problem.

Comment: @IvanChaer Apologies, that was deleted in the last edit, I will provide the correct HTML